# Grails URL id field not getting mapped to params

Tags: mongodb, grails, urlmappings.groovy

Here is my `URLmappings.groovy`

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/ewhet/$id"(controller : "ewhet", action : "show")
    "/"(view: "/index")
    "500"(view: '/error')
    }
   }
```

Here is my `ewhetController`'s `show` action:

```
class EwhetController {
    def index(){

    }
    def show(){
            def ctx = startAsync()
            ctx.start {
                render params
                //render "this invoked!!"
                ctx.complete()
            }
        }
}
```

Now when I enter the url as: `http://localhost:8080/g24/ewhet/abc`
The `abc` does not get mapped to the `params.id` and when I render `params`, I get an empty map `[:]` .  In case if url is entered as `http://localhost:8080/g24/ewhet/show?id=abc` the `id` field gets mapped to the `params.id` and I get:

```
['id':'abc']
```

So I just want to get the last part of the url mapped to the `id` parameter in `params` map without using any map in the url (like `id=abc`) as per Section 7.4.3 in [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) So how is that possible and why is my approach not working?

Kindly note that I do not have any domain classes as I am using schemaless mongodb at my backend.

Comment: if you try to comment out the first mapping /$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"  ?

Comment: @FabianoTaioli does not work!

Comment: If you change mappings to "/ewhet/$idx"(controller : "ewhet", action : "show") it's idx in params?

Comment: @FabianoTaioli I have solved it.Actually restarting app with modified URLMappings did cause the config to run.The lesson is that the URLmappings.groovy was not getting compiled.U can give that as an answer to close it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reload the app after changing the UrlMappings.groovy to assure the new config is correctly loaded.

Comment: Infact I found a more general mapping which works for me.I added this code to the urlmappings:"/$controller/$id"(action:"show")